# Display an overlay when submitting a form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to display an overlay when the user is submitting a form. I'm using `$('form').submit(function { [...] })` to achieve this.

The problem is that I'm using client-side validation. The immediate solution is of course to manually validate the form: `if ($('form').validate().valid()) { .. }`

The ultimate solution would be to hook onto some event which is invoked when the POST is made.  (To support any other plugins that might prevent the form from submitting and when the validation plugin is not used.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using [jQuery validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), you can use the `submitHandler` property to run code when the validation passes, for example:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // display overlay

        form.submit();
    }
});
```

[Further reading](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options)

Answer (score 0):

Try to `return false;` on validation errors while submiting.

Comment: I do not want to change the jquery validate plugin.

Comment: A side note: jQuery authors discourage you from returning `false` since it prevents chaining. You should always `return this;`. use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting.